# MNRAS Class - issue with natbib referencing

Tags: cross-referencing, natbib

I am using the MNRAS class in latex (https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mnras).
It uses natbib as a citation package, usepackage loaded in the .cls file.

However it does not seem to take into account my options of using "numbers" or "super"scripts within the text. It only does author-year.

Additionally i would like to be able to have those numbers listed as part of the Reference list, to run in alphabetical order, and with a number assigned to each of them.

I am provided a small working example:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fio5u9p6pi8r8vz/AACXFmzySZQ7iC5MtSyIoc2sa?dl=0

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You may want to consider posting the code of your example document directly as plain text in the question. I for one am suspicious of external links and will not download code from dropbox.

Comment: That said you are probably using the MNRAS template for a reason (the only good reason is that you want to submit to MNRAS), in that case I would assume that the template produces the expected output and would advise against meddling with it. Just follow the instructions from the documentation as closely as possible. Sometimes the workflow of publishers with regards to TeX documents is such that the output produced by their templates is not identical to the layout of the published paper, so there might not even be a need to meddle with the output.